# a ping command bat file is keep running

Tags: batch-file

I hope to ping two IP address and display result in Windows 10 with bat file, I run the following Code in *1.bat* file. But command window keep to run `ping 8.8.8.8`, you can see the *result*, why?

**Code ( 1.bat file )**

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping 4.4.4.4

cmd
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce your results. For me, `8.8.8.8` is `ping`ed 4 times, then `4.4.4.4` is pinged 4 times, as expected. I suspect that you may have some variety of format error in your `1.bat` file - perhaps you are not saving in ANSI format but in Unicode or maybe you are saving with {LF} alone as a newline instead of {CR][LF}

Comment: Thanks! you can download the file at https://www.dropbox.com/s/06dqu5ufgv19458/Ping.bat?dl=0 to test

Comment: Please don't post links to external resources as the resource reference is likely to become invalid for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simple.

Contrary to your assertion in your question that the file is named `1.bat`, you have actually named the file `ping.bat`.

So it actually executes `ping 8.8.8.8` which executes (`ping.bat` with an argument `8.8.8.8`)*

Change the name of the file to `1.bat` as you assert, then run `1` and all should be well.